# Ubuntu 13.10 - Skype not working correctly

Tags: skype, 13.10

I have updated my Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 which I have believe cause Skype not to working properly.

For example on 13.04 it was working OK, it is still working on Windows 8 (so there is nothing wrong with my internet connection), but I get the following message each time I have try to send a message:

[image]

On hover of the sign I get "Message is not sent". This should be the case if I have not got internet connection or if the person to whom I am sending the message has not got. But this is not the case...

Comment: The symbol in SuPReMe is "do not disturb"... (I have skype working ok after the upgrade, apart from the interface that changed all the colors in an awful way).

Comment: I can show you examples with people who "are online" too.

Comment: OK. I tried to reproduce it but it works for me. Apart from the interface (mine is completely black, horrible...). Which version of Skype/which desktop are you using?

Comment: Hi guys, I followed this update and it worked: [link]http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html

Comment: @payorivero The link you have given to me, solve my issue. Please, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue using the [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html)  @payorivero gave me.

The issue appears to be caused by incorrect Skype installation ( I have downloaded the Skype from its official web site).

The following line fix the problem permanently:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype %U/' /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

The above code is showing how to install Skype properly on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```